# Updating a record with Rails remote function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just wanted to know if there is any method available to update a record of a table from a view? For example am I able to delete a record from the table using the code below?

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', my_path(user), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method =>:delete, :remote=>true %></td>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      render(:update) { |page| page.reload }
    end
  end
end
```

The above code works perfectly. It deletes the record from the table and also reloads the page after clicking the destroy link. **Now, my question is: can I do the same for updating a value in my record? If so, how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, you would simply change a few things:

The method in your controller would be update:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      render(:update) { |page| page.reload }
    end
  emd
end
```

Then you would change your link to something like the following:

```
<td><%= link_to "Update", my_path(user), :method => :put, :remote => true %></td>
```

Mind you, this is under the presumption that you are in a `form_for @user` tag.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  # aforementioned link to update goes here
<% end %>
```

This is under the impression that you setup @user in the controller method (most likely `def edit`)

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: thank you very much for your immediate response that worked for me i was trying with 'update' instead of 'put'

Comment: can you please check my related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477359/why-ajax-is-not-used-when-i-submit-my-remote-update-form