# How to submit my remote update form via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a form that will edit the record, I want it to use ajax though when submitting,

```
= simple_form_for(@lesson, :html => {"data-type" => :html, :id=>'lesson_form'}, :remote=>true) do |lesson_form|

= lesson_form.button :submit, 'Update'
```

but, in the `lessons` controller at `update` action, the `request.xhr?` evaluates 0, although I am setting remote to true at the form options above; `request.xhr?` does not evaluate to true.

So, what am I missing here ? How to use ajax when update my record ? Isn't setting remote to true enough ? Any ideas please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it many ways. Some of them are:

If passing form data using GET, you can use jquery's ajax() and send the request. That way
you can use an explicit ajax trick i.e, have in-frame as medium of communication b/w form and submit. You can use this to validate the form as well, for example: checking to see if the username exists or not. In that scenerio you will have javascript interacting with your iframe and that iframe will have certain rules or markups for username that exists and vice versa.

Hope this helps. I am happy to provide you with some sample code i wrote a looooong time ago if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please provide me with some sample code of yours ? that will be a great help for sure :-)

Comment: Ok two things; one is that this is just a trick so just so you know you might want to re-write the code in ruby on rails. This is written in PHP and this was part of my project long time ago and not used anymore. here is the link to download it http://www.icplusplus.com/misc/account-available-ajax.zip